# Cannot repeatedly get the value contained in a specified cell while looping

Tags: excel, vba

Okay, so don't mind the title, I had trouble summarizing my current issue. But first here is what I am trying to do :

I have three sheets, first one is containing a list of Attributes, the second a list of Categories and the third a cross table associating Attributes and Categories.

The code i'm working on is quite straightforward : when selecting one or many attributes (or categories) using checkboxes and executing the macro, the code will look for ticked checkboxes, get the ID associated to the selected attributes (or categories), then delete the line in the attribute (or category) worksheet and also in the cross table.

The sheets looks like that :

[image: Attribute Sheet]

```
                                                 *Attribute Sheet*
```

[image: Category Sheet]

```
                                                 *Category Sheet*
```

[image: Cross Table Sheet]

```
                                                  *Cross Table*
```

And here is my code :

```
Sub Delete_Selection()

    Dim Wb As Workbook: Set Wb = Workbooks("DataBase WIP.xlsm")
    Dim Sws As Worksheet: Set Sws = ActiveSheet
    Dim CrossWs As Worksheet: Set CrossWs = Sheet6
    Dim Cb As CheckBox
    Dim Checking As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = Sws.Cells(Sws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim CRow As Long, IDColumn As Long, IDRow As Long
    Dim CID As String
    
    IDColumn = Sws.Cells.Find(What:="ID", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column 'Look for the ID column in the current sheet
    
    MsgBox (IDColumn) 'Debug purpose
    
    For Each Cb In Sws.Checkboxes
        
        If (Cb.Value = 1) Then 'If checkbox is ticked, proceed
        
            CRow = Range(Cb.LinkedCell).Row 'Get the row number of the checkbox
            MsgBox (CRow) 'Debug purpose
            CID = Cells(CRow, IDColumn).Value 'Get the ID value
            Rows(CRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp 'Delete the row
            Cb.Delete 'Delete the checkbox
        
            If (ActiveSheet.CodeName = "Sheet2") Then 'If attributes are being deleted, proceed
            
                MsgBox (CID) 'Debug Purpose
                IDRow = CrossWs.Cells.Find(What:=CID, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row 'Find the corresponding row in the cross table
                CrossWs.Rows(IDRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp 'Delete it
                
            End If
            
            If (ActiveSheet.CodeName = "Sheet5") Then 'If categories are being deleted, proceed
                
                MsgBox (CID) 'Debug Purpose
                IDColumn = CrossWs.Cells.Find(What:=CID, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column 'Find the corresponding column in the cross table
                CrossWs.Columns(IDColumn).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft 'Delete it
            
            End If
        
        End If
        
    Next
    
End Sub
```

The issue :

- The code works perfectly fine when selecting and deleting multiple attributes
- The code works when selecting and deleting one category
- BUT : when selecting multiple categories and running the deletion code, it deletes them all in the category sheet but it only delete one corresponding column in the cross table.

Example : if I want to delete the beef and beans category, I select them using the checkboxes then press the button, in the category sheet they're all successfully deleted (yay !) but only the beef column will be deleted in the crosstable.

So to figure out why, I decided to print the relevant variables, what is happening in the previous example is the following :

- IDColumn = 1 which is normal
- CRow = 10 fine too
- CID = DOC9 expected
  Then
- IDColumn = 1 Wasn't supposed to change
- Crow = 10 The rows have been shifted up to fill the gap so totally normal
- CID = "" And that's where my issue is.

Despite looking at the right cell, CID don't get the value contained in it and I don't understand why at all.

Important precision, the attribute sheet is perfectly normal while the category sheet contains a Table ! I think that's where the issue lies but I couldn't find anything useful on the Internet.

And I don't understand why the program would be able the read the value of a cell the first time and then doesn't. I may have missed something obvious so I apologize if its the case but any help would be greatly appreciated !

**Edit 1 :** It has nothing to do with the Categories being in a table, I wrote a similar code but I ran into the exact same issue even without looking at a Table. I still don't know what's happening.

I found a workaround by first reading all my ID's and storing them into an array and then looping through my array to modify my cross table. I will probably do the same for my current issue.

Comment: Just an idea: do you loose the value of CID if you comment out all 4 `.Delete` rows?

Comment: I commented the code deleting the rows in the Category sheet and ran the code :
- The Row index are fine but CID only get the first ID, not the second one, even if no rows are deleted, I'm even more confused now ahah

Comment: You may give a try NOT to delete `cb` within the `For Each` loop.

Comment: I tried that already, didn't change anything, but It shouldn't be an issue because this segment of the code works totally fine on the Attribute WorkSheet, meaning CID gets the correct values everytime. 

I think it has something to do with the fact that the category ID and the category name columns are a Table, while in the attribute Worksheet, they are normal columns

Comment: I tried putting a Workbook.RefreshAll at the beginning of the loop instructions but it doesn't change anything

Comment: What if you change `CID = Cells(CRow, IDColumn).Value` to `CID = sws.Cells(CRow, IDColumn).Value`? One of the `.Find`s may change the activesheet.

Comment: Nope doesn't change anything, I will maybe try to look for another way to code this, idk, I'd really like to know what's happening here

Comment: Just 2 more things: I'd set a breakpoint at `CID = Cells...` and analyze the values. And it is always beneficial using sheet pointers when hoping among sheets like `sws.cells` or `sws.rows`

Comment: Can you share your sample file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the problem.

Once again I wasted a lot of time because of a stupid mistake.

When I was deleting a category, I needed to find the column linked to that category in my cross table, and I stupidly used the same variable referring to the ID column of my Category sheet (i.e. "IDColumn"), changing its value and therefore when reading the next ID, my code was looking in the wrong cell.

Thanks to anyone who have tried to help me ! I will hopefully not make a fool of myself next time ahah.